# Enumerate protocols implemented for Clojure type

Tags: clojure, protocols, enumerate

How do I retrieve a list of protocols that a Clojure type has been extended with?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `supers`:

```
(supers (class {})) 

=> #{clojure.lang.AFn java.lang.Iterable java.lang.Runnable 
     clojure.lang.IPersistentMap clojure.lang.IEditableCollection 
     clojure.lang.IObj clojure.lang.MapEquivalence java.io.Serializable 
     clojure.lang.IKVReduce clojure.lang.IMapIterable java.util.Map 
     clojure.lang.APersistentMap clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection 
     clojure.lang.IFn clojure.lang.Associative clojure.lang.Counted 
     clojure.lang.Seqable java.lang.Object clojure.lang.IHashEq 
     clojure.lang.IMeta clojure.lang.ILookup java.util.concurrent.Callable}
```

---

When in doubt, you can also experiment with other stuff found perusing [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).  For example:

```
(parents (class {})) => 
#{clojure.lang.IEditableCollection clojure.lang.IObj
  clojure.lang.IKVReduce clojure.lang.IMapIterable
  clojure.lang.APersistentMap}

(ancestors (class {})) => 
#{clojure.lang.AFn java.lang.Iterable java.lang.Runnable
  clojure.lang.IPersistentMap clojure.lang.IEditableCollection
  clojure.lang.IObj clojure.lang.MapEquivalence java.io.Serializable
  clojure.lang.IKVReduce clojure.lang.IMapIterable java.util.Map
  clojure.lang.APersistentMap clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection
  clojure.lang.IFn clojure.lang.Associative clojure.lang.Counted
  clojure.lang.Seqable java.lang.Object clojure.lang.IHashEq
  clojure.lang.IMeta clojure.lang.ILookup java.util.concurrent.Callable}

(bases (class {})) => 
(clojure.lang.APersistentMap
 clojure.lang.IObj
 clojure.lang.IEditableCollection
 clojure.lang.IMapIterable
 clojure.lang.IKVReduce)

; Mostly synonyms
(class {}) => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
(type  {}) => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

Comment: And you could filter interfaces like this: `(filter (memfn isInterface) (supers (class {})))`

Comment: These are interfaces, not protocols. This won't cover any protocols you extend to a type after the type is already defined.

Comment: @akond I was referring more to the answer itself than your comment on it. If you're only looking at superclasses you might as well filter for interfaces, but either way you'll miss protocols extended after type definition.